# Ethernet RJ45 diagnostic port beside LSA+ block

Tags: resistors, ethernet

I have a remote logging device that has an LSA+ block on the PCB for a 100Mbps Ethernet cable to the router, 50m away. Right beside the LSA+ block is an RJ45 socket, which the document says is "for local diagnostic purposes that is directly in parallel with the LSA+ block, so don't connect to both ports simultaneously".

When I first arrive on-site, it is easy to unplug the remote end of the Ethernet cable from the router before going to the logger, connecting to the local RJ45 port, do the diagnostics with the front panel, and restore everything before leaving again. But while I'm connected to the local RJ45, I can't help thinking that there's this 50m antenna for each of the four RX/TX wires that is just inviting interference. I mean it works all right, but still...

I'm thinking I could easily make a little RJ45 socket box with termination resistors that I plug onto the remote end of the Ethernet cable after unplugging it from the router. But what value(s) should the RX and TX resistors be, given that there's no ground reference?

Or is this a truly unnecessary step?

Comment: What do you mean by 50m antenna?  A length of CAT cable?  Is it perhaps twisted or shielded?

Comment: It is impossible to know how the device works unless we see the schematics. If they are wired in parallel, and it really is Ethernet, don't put anything at the remote end, as the 
there would be triple termination. It would be best to disconnect the Ethernet cable at the device end, not at the router end.

Ethernet is a differential bus and the cables are 100 ohm differential so it would need 100 ohm terminations. But since you don't know how it works, it is best to leave it unterminated. Or ask someone who has designed it.

Comment: @KH Indeed CAT-5 (-6? Dunno) cable, and yes definitely Ethernet and twisted, but I can’t see a shield. And the ends aren’t connected to anything, which makes it an antenna

Comment: @Justme Sadly, no schematics, so I’m just taking the documentation at its word. Sure, I should disconnect the long cable locally, but LSA+ is “permanent” - not for regular dis-/re-connecting